# MYSQL: Display consecutive rows

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one called `reference` and one called `details`. Details joins to reference by `reference_uid` and details can have multiple rows for one reference uid. Details has three fields called `last_time` which is a date field, `callback_reason_uid` and `contact_reason_uid`. I want to find any reference_uid that has 3 or more consecutive contact_reason_uids (contact_reason_uid number doesn't matter so long as it isn't 0) across 3 or more days.

Details table:

```
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| details_uid | reference_uid | last_time   |  callback_reason_uid   | contact_reason_uid |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|           1 |             1 | 2013-10-10  |                     1  |                  0 |
|           2 |             1 | 2013-10-11  |                     0  |                  1 |
|           3 |             1 | 2013-10-12  |                     0  |                  1 |
|           4 |             1 | 2013-10-13  |                     0  |                  1 |
|           5 |             2 | 2013-10-10  |                     0  |                  1 |
|           6 |             2 | 2013-10-11  |                     0  |                  1 |
|           7 |             2 | 2013-10-11  |                     0  |                  1 |
|           8 |             2 | 2013-10-12  |                     1  |                  0 |
|           9 |             3 | 2013-10-15  |                     0  |                  1 |
|          10 |             3 | 2013-10-17  |                     0  |                  1 |
|          11 |             3 | 2013-10-18  |                     0  |                  1 |
|          12 |             3 | 2013-10-19  |                     1  |                  0 |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

So in the above example, I would see reference_uid 1 and 3 because they had 3 consecutive contact_reasons_uids across 3 different days. I would not see reference_uid 2 even though it has 3 consecutive contact_reason_uids, it is not across 3 different days. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry. For the avoidance of doubt, can you define 'consecutive'?

Comment: I'm looking for any reference_uid that has 3 or more contact_reason_uids in a row across 3 or more days

Comment: Do you mean 4 different days? reference_uid 2 has records for 2013-10-10, 2013-10-11 and 2013-10-12 which is 3 days. But you said you don't want this included in the results?